# How to set a favicon for an XUL window?

Tags: firefox, browser, firefox-addon, xul

I open my Firefox extension window in a browser's tab. Is it possible to set a favicon for that tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code from the Mozilla site does not work correctly - it produces the following error message: "Warning: XUL box for box element contained an inline link child, forcing all its children to be wrapped in a block". If this code is placed between 'window' tags it messes up all other controls on the window. If it is placed between 'box' tags, window controls are rendered fine, but still there is this error message. The problem was solved by adding the display property and setting it to "none".
The working code looks like this:

```
<window xmlns="mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul";
        xmlns:html="w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<!-- Icon from chrome -->
<html:link rel="icon" href="chrome://myExtension/content/path/to/favicon.png"
           style="display:none"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create this Folder structure inside the chrome folder

> \icons\default

if your window id is **mainwindow** create a file named **mainwindow.ico** or **mainwindow.xpm**

Comment: Note that this only works for add-ons which are extracted ([unpacked](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Install_Manifests#unpack)) and [Overlay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Overlay_Extensions).

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create an icon for a XUL window. By creating files yourwindow.ico or yourwindow.xpm where yourwindow is the ID of your XUL window. And place the files in your directory structure like this :  chrome/icons/default
This will override the global icon files.
More Information about XUL window and icon can be found here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/window

Comment: Hi, Meher Ranjan. Thank you for your reply. I followed the link you provided and it says that the icon file should be placed in the <mozilla-directory>/chrome/icons/default/ directory. I am not quite comfortable with that, cos I would prefer that all my extension files would be only in the extension's directory. However, following your link even further I have found a solution at the very bottom of that page.
Thank you for directing me.

Comment: <window xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"
 xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<!-- Icon from chrome -->
<html:link rel="icon" href="chrome://myExtension/content/path/to/favicon.png"/>

Comment: Note that this only works for add-ons which are extracted ([unpacked](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Install_Manifests#unpack)) and [Overlay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Overlay_Extensions).